# What is "?" doing in variable definition?

Tags: typescript

I saw sometimes people using "?" in variable definition `imageURL?: string;` and I don't know what is usage for. Here is some sample code that I found in local storage:

```
interface Account {
    displayName: string;
    id: string;
    imageURL?: string;
    name?: string;
    rpDisplayName: string;
}

interface AddEventListenerOptions extends EventListenerOptions {
    once?: boolean;
    passive?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: It's not django code. It's typescript.

Comment: It does not look like django expression. However, in Python, `? = match 0 or 1 repetitions` and it works as conditional in C++.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language is **Typescript** and this question mark is here to label the property as being **optional**.

```
interface Animal {
    legs: number;
    wings?: number;
}
```

From this definition you can do the following:

```
const cat: Animal = { legs: 4 };
const bird: Animal = { legs: 2, wings: 2 };
```

From the [Typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

> Not all properties of an interface may be required. Some exist under certain conditions or may not be there at all. These optional properties are popular when creating patterns like “option bags” where you pass an object to a function that only has a couple of properties filled in.

Comment: thank you, i'm new in django , i just saw this code in a github project.your answer is very helpful.